# Something about going in circles

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

This is a problem that has been troubling me for a while and in essence, i would like for someone to point out my mistakes.

In Do Carmo's book on Differential Geometry, the following phrasing is used a few times :

Let $\varphi_i: [t_i,t_{i+1}] \rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function which measures at each angle the positive angle from $x_u$ to $\alpha'(t)$, where $\alpha$ is a simple closed, piecewise regular, parametrized curve with vertices $\alpha(t_i)$ and external angles $\theta_i$.

> Theorem of turning tangents : With the above notation we have for plane curves :
>
> $$\sum_i\left(\varphi(t_{i+1}) - \varphi(t_{i})  \right) + \sum_i \theta_i = \pm 2 \pi$$

In other versions of the book, like the one linked above, the parametrization $x:U \subset R^2 \rightarrow S\subset R^3$, $U$ is homeomorphic to the open disk in the plane and compatible with the orientation of $S$.

Now, the positive angle from $x_u$ to some vector field along a curve, comes up often in this section of the book.

> Trying to apply the theorem of turning tangents for a curve whose trace is a circle $\gamma(v) = (\cos(v),\sin(v),0)$ of radius 1. I keep finding myself wanting to find a parametrization such that $x_u$ is tangent to the curve. For example, define
> \begin{aligned}
> x_1:(0,2)\times (0,2\pi) &\rightarrow R^3,\\ (u,v) &\mapsto (u \cos(v),u \sin(v),0)
> \end{aligned}
> And
> \begin{aligned}
> x_2:(0,2)\times (-\pi,\pi) &\rightarrow R^3,\\ (u,v) &\mapsto (-u \cos(v),u \sin(v),0)
> \end{aligned}
>
> Then of course, piecewise, $x_v$ is tangent to the curve (for each map for all the curve except for a single point). And the angle is therefore constantly $0$, but you can't apply it, because it seems to limit you to one parametrization (which means to me, that it's just a local theorem, which makes sense, as it's used to prove Gauss Bonnet).

Therefore it seems impossible to find a parametrization with that property of tangency to the coordinate curves.
I think, in fact, that the proof is just one step away from :

> Since $\alpha : [0,L]$ is closed, it has the property that $\alpha(L) = \alpha(0)$. Suppose you had a parametrization such that : $\alpha'(t) = x_u(\alpha(t))$ for all $t$, and $\alpha(t) = x(u(t),v(t))$, by the uniqueness property of the solution to that differential equation (or something like that), $x$ can't be a homeomorphism (since it wouldn't satisfy injectivity at $(u(L),v(L))$.

But this also means that the angle must change over the curve, it cannot remain $0$, unless it's on a geodesic, but since we are limiting ourselves to plane curves, any curving away eliminates us.

P.S. Those questions emerged as i was trying to answer the following question (which i will soon) : [Do carmo: theorem of turning tangents --- notational confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331486/do-carmo-theorem-of-turning-tangents-notational-confusion)

Comment: You might be interested in looking at [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/users/user317/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). Relative to coordinate charts adapted to a closed curve, see in particular Example 2 on pp. 82-83. Relative to the Hopf Umlaufsatz, see Lemma 3.6 on p. 27.

Comment: @TedShifrin I actually already downloaded your book yesterday! I will have a look. Thank you.